# IIS / Server misconfiguration ASP.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, webserver

I have IIS 8.5 on a server and a simple http GET ASP.NET Web API service hosted there which returns JSON object. When I access this service from localhost or any other server in my network (using browser, Postman, code) the service works. But when I try to access the same url from one specific server (again using browser, Postman, code) I am getting http error code 403 and html response with text:
"Access Denied. You are attempting to access a forbidden site. Consult your system administrator for details.".
The service does not have any kind of authentication and it never returns error 403. Has anybody ever met such a strange behavior?

Comment: Get started from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code

Comment: The specific reason cannot be seen simply from the 403, you need to provide the sub-status code.However, I think it is likely that the device's network and firewall restrict the access to the IP. You can check it.

Comment: Looks like the requests do not go to the service from the specified server. At least, there are no any logs when accessing the service. However, telnet works.

Comment: @BruceZhang any ideas where to dig further?

Comment: What is the difference in the network environment between a specific server and other servers? Do you mean that all requests from a specific server are not recorded in the IIS log, or is it just that 403 is not recorded?